# ExpressJS: What's the difference between ?, +, * in string patterns and regexes?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, express

Hi I'm new to Express and although I have scoured the internet for a complete explanation of string patterns I haven't found any.  The documentation for [path-to-regexp](https://github.com/component/path-to-regexp) doesn't seem to help, either.

Specifically, I'm trying to interpret this (IMO rather cryptic) remark in the documentation:

> The characters ?, +, *, and () are subsets of their Regular Expression counterparts.

See http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html

How differently do these characters behave between regexes and string patterns?  Would anyone know of a complete list of characters deemed special in Express strings, with explanations about what they are supposed to do?

Cheers

Comment: 0 or 1, 1 or more, 0 or more

Comment: `*` doesn't seem to be strictly 0 or more, though. It seems to be a true wildcard, the likes of `/.*/`. These nuanced differences are what I'm after

Comment: Just a comment on [Express Route Tester](http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/) in case you're using that to derive conclusions, I think it's either outdated or not working correctly. I entered Route: `*` and Path: `/path/value` which *should* match, and does too when I test it in a real express app, but there in the results it shows it doesn't match.

Comment: @jfriend00 I disagree. The first examples are not regexes as such.

Comment: @jfriend00 No, the 3rd example shows that `*` here is not the same as `*` in a regex. (Not to be confused with the example at the end where it actually is a regex.)

Answer (score 2):

That means that you cannot use "regular" regular-expressions, but you can use a "subset" of regex while determining the routes for an ExpressJS app.

> How differently do these characters behave between regexes and string
>   patterns? Would anyone know of a complete list of characters deemed
>   special in Express strings, with explanations about what they are
>   supposed to do?

The characters deemed special are these ones that were mentioned, `?, +, *, and ()P` , meaning that, even though ExpressJS doens't fully support Regex, these characters **behave exactly like they would behave if that was a Regex**.

The Express routing documentation already gives you examples:

```
// will match acd and abcd
app.get('/ab?cd', function(req, res) {
  res.send('ab?cd');
});

// will match abcd, abbcd, abbbcd, and so on
app.get('/ab+cd', function(req, res) {
  res.send('ab+cd');
});

// will match abcd, abxcd, abRABDOMcd, ab123cd, and so on
app.get('/ab*cd', function(req, res) {
  res.send('ab*cd');
});

// will match /abe and /abcde
app.get('/ab(cd)?e', function(req, res) {
 res.send('ab(cd)?e');
});
```

If these examples don't suffice, and you want to go deeper, I recommend you learning Regex: [REGEX, best way to learn it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16461680/regex-best-way-to-learn-it)

I also recommend using [Regex101](http://www.regex101.com) while studying. You can test the regexes from the examples above and it will **explain it to you in the top right corner**.

Example:

[image: Regex]

Again, remember that, from the whole Regex special characters, only `?, +, *, and ()P` will work on Express routing.

Answer (score 1):

From the examples it looks like `+` and `?` behave as you'd expect in regexes, and `*` is equivalent to the regex `.*`. That's for string patterns - the actual regex ones further down behave as you'd expect.